# UICollectionViewCell has no subviews (besides contentView) until it is added to any parent view

Tags: xcode, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nib

Firstly, here is the only question I found that could possibly be related: [viewWithTag in UICollectionViewCell returns nil in Swift (until cell is reused)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108337/viewwithtag-in-uicollectionviewcell-returns-nil-in-swift-until-cell-is-reused)

I'm using Xcode 7.1.1 and actually have another `UIcollectionView` in my storyboard that works fine. I can find no difference between the one that works and this one.

Here is the code proving my craziness (from inside cellForItemAtIndexPath):

```swift
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("VariantCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

let cellBeforeCount    = cell.subviews.count
let contentBeforeCount = cell.contentView.subviews.count

self.view.addSubview(cell)

let cellAfterCount    = cell.subviews.count
let contentAfterCount = cell.contentView.subviews.count

print("\(cellBeforeCount) \(contentBeforeCount) \(cellAfterCount) \(contentAfterCount)")`
```

cellBeforeCount == 1, contentBeforeCount = 0, cellAfterCount == 4, contentAfterCount == 0

Here is the storyboard in XML for this VC:

[image: Storyboard source code]

As you can see, the first view in the `<collectionViewCell>` is a view whose key is `contentView` and my labels (you can only see the first) are subviews of it.

Why in the world would none of the subviews exist until after the cell was added to a parent view and why aren't the subviews being added to the contentView? The two have to be related, right?

Comment: What's the purpose of this line 'self.view.addSubview(cell)' ?

Comment: Just to show that there are no subviews in my cell until after it has a parent view. I subclassed my cell and from inside `awakeFromNib` it has no subviews. BUT, from inside `layoutSubviews` they are all there. It was that fact that made me think that perhaps it wasn't until the cell actually drop into another view did it have its own subviews. To test that assumption, I just added the cell to the first view I could think of (which happened to be self.view).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, chalk it up to not understanding Size Classes. I disabled it and the cell now has subviews as expected: [image]

It makes sense given that the cell has no idea the size of its parent, so it doesn't know which constraints/views to render. This also explains why the cell would have subviews after being added to any parent (and can thus infer its size).

This is an iPad app, so I don't need Size Classes.

I hope this helps someone.